# Use observer pattern in client-server JavaFx

Tags: javafx, client-server, observer-pattern

As a seminar, I was asked to implement a phone book on a file and use a design pattern. I chose the observer. The implementation is a client-server. I created a server class that manages the file. The client communicate to the server, and the client thread registered to the observer. My goal is to whenever there is an update of the file (deletion, adding etc.) all the clients's GUI refresh.
I would like for help.

The server class:

```
public class Server extends Application implements Observer {
//implements Observer 
private TextArea ta = new TextArea();
private int clientNo = 0;
private int flag = 0;
private int lockId;
private RandomAccessFile raf;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList<HandleAClient> clients;
private HandleAClient clientThread;
//Specify the size of five string fields in the record
final static int NAME_SIZE = 32;
final static int STREET_SIZE = 32;
final static int CITY_SIZE = 20;
final static int STATE_SIZE = 2;
final static int ZIP_SIZE = 5;
final static int RECORD_SIZE = (NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE 
        + CITY_SIZE + STATE_SIZE + ZIP_SIZE);
private int[] fromToSortChoices =
    { 0, NAME_SIZE, NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE ,
        NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE + CITY_SIZE ,
        NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE + CITY_SIZE + STATE_SIZE,
        NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE + CITY_SIZE + STATE_SIZE + ZIP_SIZE
    };
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
final static String fileName0 = "address0";
public static void main(String[] args)
{ launch(args);
}
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    // Open or create a random access file
    try
    { 
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName0 + ".dat", "rw");
        raf.setLength(0);
        this.clients = new ArrayList<Server.HandleAClient>();
    }
    catch (IOException e1) 
    { System.out.print("Error: " + e1);
    System.exit(0);          
    }
    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta), 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
        try{
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch(Exception e1){
        }});

    new Thread( () ->{
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            Platform.runLater(() ->
            ta.appendText("Server started at " + new Date() + '\n'));
            while(true){
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                clientNo++;
                Platform.runLater(() ->
                ta.appendText("Starting thread for client " + clientNo + " at " + new Date() + '\n'));

                InetAddress clientInetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();
                Platform.runLater(() ->{
                    ta.appendText("Client " + clientNo + "'s host name is " + clientInetAddress.getHostName() + "\n");
                    ta.appendText("Client " + clientNo + "'s IP Address is " + clientInetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n");
                });

                clientThread = 
                        new HandleAClient(socket,clientNo);
                Thread t = new Thread(clientThread);
                clientThread.addObserver(Server.this);
                clients.add(clientThread);
                t.start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }).start();
}
class HandleAClient extends Observable implements Runnable {
    //extends Observable
    private Socket connectToClient; 
    private int id;
    private long currentPosition = 0;
    DataInputStream FromClient;
    DataOutputStream ToClient;
    public HandleAClient(Socket socket,int id) {
        this.connectToClient = socket;
        this.id = id;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create data input and output streams
            FromClient = 
                    new DataInputStream(connectToClient.getInputStream());
            ToClient = 
                    new DataOutputStream(connectToClient.getOutputStream());
            currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
            ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
            long fromPosition = raf.getFilePointer() - 2 * RECORD_SIZE;
            long numberOfRecordsToCopy = 
                    (raf.length()- fromPosition) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
            long numberOfRecords;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("server wait");
                //  synchronized (Thread.class) {
                ToClient.writeLong(raf.length());
                ToClient.flush();
                String type = FromClient.readUTF();
                switch (type) {
                case ("Clear"):
                {
                    raf.setLength(0);
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                }
                break;
                case ("Add"):
                {                       
                    writeAddress(raf.length());
                    //currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);

                }
                break;
                case ("First"):
                {
                    System.out.println("server start first");
                    if (raf.length() > 0)   readAddress(0);
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                    System.out.println("server done first");
                }
                break;
                case ("Next"):
                {
                    currentPosition = FromClient.readLong();
                    if (currentPosition < raf.length()) {
                        readAddress(currentPosition);}
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);

                }
                break;
                case ("Previous"):
                {
                    currentPosition = FromClient.readLong();
                    if (currentPosition - 2 * 2 * RECORD_SIZE > 0)
                        readAddress(currentPosition - 2 * 2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    else if (raf.length() > 0) readAddress(0);
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case ("Last"):
                {
                    long lastPosition = raf.length();
                    ToClient.writeLong(lastPosition);
                    if (lastPosition > 0)
                        readAddress(lastPosition - 2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case ("Midst"):
                {
                    numberOfRecords = (raf.length()) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(numberOfRecords);
                    if (numberOfRecords > 0)
                        readAddress((numberOfRecords/2)*(2*RECORD_SIZE));
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case "Update":
                {
                    currentPosition = FromClient.readLong();
                    if (currentPosition > 0) {
                        currentPosition = currentPosition - 2*RECORD_SIZE;
                        ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);}
                    writeAddress(currentPosition);
                    //currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case "Delete":
                {
                    currentPosition = FromClient.readLong();
                    numberOfRecords = (raf.length()) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(numberOfRecords);
                    if (numberOfRecords == 0) {
                        currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                        ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (numberOfRecords == 1) 
                    {
                        raf.setLength(0);
                        currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                        ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                        return;
                    }
                    fromPosition = currentPosition;
                    long toPosition = fromPosition - 2*RECORD_SIZE;
                    numberOfRecordsToCopy = (raf.length()- fromPosition) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(numberOfRecordsToCopy);
                    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecordsToCopy; i++ )
                    { 
                        readAddress(fromPosition);
                        writeAddress(toPosition);
                        fromPosition += 2*RECORD_SIZE;
                        toPosition += 2*RECORD_SIZE;       
                    }
                    raf.setLength(raf.length() - 2*RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(raf.length());
                    readAddress(0);
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case "Insert":
                {
                    currentPosition = FromClient.readLong();
                    if (raf.length() == 0)
                    { 
                        writeAddress(raf.length());
                        ToClient.writeLong(raf.getFilePointer());
                        return;
                    }
                    fromPosition = currentPosition-2*RECORD_SIZE;
                    long currentFrom = raf.length() - 2*RECORD_SIZE; 
                    numberOfRecordsToCopy = (raf.length()- fromPosition) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(numberOfRecordsToCopy);
                    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecordsToCopy; i++ )
                    { 
                        readAddress(currentFrom);
                        writeAddress(currentFrom + 2*RECORD_SIZE);
                        currentFrom -= 2*RECORD_SIZE;
                    }
                    writeAddress(fromPosition);
                    raf.setLength(raf.length() - 2*RECORD_SIZE);
                    readAddress(0);
                    currentPosition = raf.getFilePointer();
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case "Duplicate":
                {
                    numberOfRecords = (raf.length()) / (2 * RECORD_SIZE);
                    ToClient.writeLong(numberOfRecords);
                    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecords; i++ )
                    {
                        readAddress(i*2*RECORD_SIZE);
                        writeAddress(raf.length());  
                    }
                    if (numberOfRecords>0) readAddress(0);
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                    ToClient.writeLong(currentPosition);
                }
                break;
                case "Sort":
                {
                    sortFile();
                    if (raf.length() > 0)   
                    {
                        readAddress(0);
                    }
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                }
                break;
                }

                //}

                Platform.runLater(() ->{
                    ta.appendText("Done operation for client "+ this.id + "\n");
                });

            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }


    private void sortFile() {
        try {
            int size = (int) (raf.length() / RECORD_SIZE / 2);
            int ascORdes, from, to, idx;
            raf.seek(0);
            if (raf.length() == 0) return ;
            ascORdes = FromClient.readBoolean() ? -1 : 1;
            String fileToSort[];
            fileToSort = new String[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
            { 
                fileToSort[i] = 
                        FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(RECORD_SIZE, raf);
            }       
            idx  = FromClient.readInt();
            from = fromToSortChoices[idx];
            to   = fromToSortChoices[idx+1];
            HeapSortaORd.heapSortaORd(fileToSort, ascORdes, from, to);
            raf.seek(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
            { 
                FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(
                        fileToSort[i], RECORD_SIZE, raf);
            }       

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void readAddress(long position) {
        try {
            raf.seek(position);
            String name = 
                    FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(NAME_SIZE, raf);
            String street = 
                    FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(STREET_SIZE, raf);
            String city = 
                    FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(CITY_SIZE, raf);
            String state = 
                    FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(STATE_SIZE, raf);
            String zip = 
                    FixedLengthStringIO.readFixedLengthString(ZIP_SIZE, raf);
            ToClient.flush();
            ToClient.writeUTF(name);
            ToClient.flush();
            ToClient.writeUTF(street);
            ToClient.flush();
            ToClient.writeUTF(city);
            ToClient.flush();
            ToClient.writeUTF(state);
            ToClient.flush();
            ToClient.writeUTF(zip);
            ToClient.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
    private void writeAddress(long position) {
        try
        {   raf.seek(position);
        String name = FromClient.readUTF();
        String street = FromClient.readUTF();
        String city = FromClient.readUTF();
        String state = FromClient.readUTF();
        String zip = FromClient.readUTF();
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(name 
                == null ? " " : name, NAME_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(street 
                == null ? " " : street, STREET_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(city 
                == null ? " " : city, CITY_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(state 
                == null ? " " : state, STATE_SIZE, raf);
        FixedLengthStringIO.writeFixedLengthString(zip
                == null ? " " : zip, ZIP_SIZE, raf);
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        { e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
    this.flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("File changed. Client " + clients.get(i).id + " back to first");
        clients.get(i).currentPosition = 0;
    }

}

 }
```

The client class:

```
public class Client extends Application
//extends Observable
 { // IO streams
    DataOutputStream toServer = null;
    DataInputStream fromServer = null;
Socket socket;
//Specify the size of five string fields in the record
final static int NAME_SIZE = 32;
final static int STREET_SIZE = 32;
final static int CITY_SIZE = 20;
final static int STATE_SIZE = 2;
final static int ZIP_SIZE = 5;
final static int RECORD_SIZE = (NAME_SIZE + STREET_SIZE 
        + CITY_SIZE + STATE_SIZE + ZIP_SIZE);
final static String fileName0 = "address0";
// Text fields
private TextField jtfName = new TextField();
private TextField jtfStreet = new TextField();
private TextField jtfCity = new TextField();
private TextField jtfState = new TextField(); 
private TextField jtfZip = new TextField();
// Buttons
private Button jbtAdd   = new Button("Add");
private Button jbtFirst   = new Button("First");
private Button jbtNext   = new Button("Next");
private Button jbtPrevious   = new Button("Previous");
private Button jbtLast   = new Button("Last");
private Button jbtMidst   = new Button("Midst");
private Button jbtUpdate   = new Button("Update");
private Button jbtDelete   = new Button("Delete");
private Button jbtInsert   = new Button("Insert");
private Button jbtClear   = new Button("Clear");
private Button jbtDuplicate   = new Button("Duplicate");
private Button jbtDoSort   = new Button("Perform Sort");
private GridPane jpSortPanel;
private RadioButton jrbSortDecsend;
private RadioButton jrbSortAcsend;
private ToggleGroup bgSortType;
private ObservableList<String> sortChoices =  
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Name",  "Street",  "City", "State", "Zip");
private GridPane mainPane =new GridPane();
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ComboBox jcbSortChoices;
private DataOutputStream ToServer;
private DataInputStream FromServer;
private long fileLength;
private long currentPosition;
private long numberOfRecords;
private long numberOfRecordsToCopy;
private TextArea ta = new TextArea();
private int flag = 0;
@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

    /** Make scene and add to Application **/
    jtfName.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    jtfStreet.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    jtfCity.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    jtfState.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    jtfZip.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    // Panel jpAddress for holding labels & text fields
    GridPane jpAddress = new GridPane();
    String LabelColumn[]={"Name","Street","City"};
    Label l[]=new Label[LabelColumn.length];
    for(int i=0;i<LabelColumn.length;i++)
    { 
        l[i] = new Label(LabelColumn[i]);
        l[i].setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    jpAddress.addColumn(0,l);
    // Panel jpStateZip for holding state and zip
    GridPane jpStateZip = new GridPane();
    jpStateZip.addRow(0, new Label("State"),jtfState,new Label("Zip"),jtfZip);
    // Panel p3 for holding jtfCity and jpStateZip
    GridPane p3 = new GridPane();
    p3.addRow(0, jtfCity,jpStateZip);
    growChildren(jpStateZip);
    growChildren(p3);
    jpAddress.addColumn(1, jtfName, jtfStreet,p3);
    // Set the panel with line border
    jpAddress.getStyleClass().add(
            "{ -fx-border-color: black;-fx-border-width: 5;}");
    growChildren(jpAddress);
    // Add buttons to a panel
    GridPane jpButton = new GridPane();
    HBox hb = new HBox();
    hb.getChildren().addAll(jbtAdd,jbtFirst,jbtNext,jbtPrevious,jbtLast,jbtMidst,jbtUpdate,jbtDelete,jbtInsert,jbtClear,jbtDuplicate);
    jpButton.addRow(0, hb);
    growChildren(jpButton);
    // Add jpAddress and jpButton to the mainPane
    mainPane.addColumn(0, jpAddress,jpButton,ta);
    /* ============ sort Panel ============ */
    jpSortPanel       = new GridPane();
    jrbSortAcsend     = new RadioButton("Ascending");
    jrbSortAcsend.setSelected(true);
    jrbSortDecsend    = new RadioButton("descending");
    jcbSortChoices    = new ComboBox<String>(sortChoices);
    jcbSortChoices.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    bgSortType        = new ToggleGroup();
    bgSortType.getToggles().addAll(jrbSortAcsend,jrbSortDecsend);
    jpSortPanel.addColumn(0, jrbSortAcsend,jrbSortDecsend,jcbSortChoices);
    growChildren(jpSortPanel);
    /* ========== end of sort panel ======= */
    jbtDoSort.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    mainPane.addColumn(1, jpSortPanel,jbtDoSort);
    growChildren(mainPane);

    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
        // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
        FromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        // Create an output stream to send data to the server
        ToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            try{
                socket.close();
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);

            }
            catch(Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }});

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    jbtClear.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Clear");
            clearTextFields();
            currentPosition = 0;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("client done clear");
    });
    jbtAdd.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Add");
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done add");

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    jbtFirst.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        System.out.println("client start first");
        try {
            first();
            System.out.println("client done first");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtNext.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Next");
            ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
            if (currentPosition < fileLength) {

                readAddress();}
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();

            System.out.println("client done next");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtPrevious.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Previous");
            ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
            if (currentPosition - 2 * 2 * RECORD_SIZE > 0)
                readAddress();
            else if (fileLength > 0) readAddress();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done previous");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtLast.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Last");
            long lastPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            if (lastPosition > 0)
                readAddress();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done last");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtMidst.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Midst");
            numberOfRecords = FromServer.readLong();
            if (numberOfRecords > 0)
                readAddress();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done midst");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtUpdate.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Update");
            ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
            if (currentPosition > 0) 
                currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done update");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtDelete.setOnAction(e ->
    {   try {
        fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
        ToServer.writeUTF("Delete");
        ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
        numberOfRecords = FromServer.readLong();
        if (numberOfRecords == 0) {
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            return;
        }
        else if (numberOfRecords == 1) 
        { 
            clearTextFields();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            return;
        }
        numberOfRecordsToCopy = FromServer.readLong();
        for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecordsToCopy; i++ )
        { 
            readAddress();
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());
        }
        fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
        readAddress();
        currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
        System.out.println("client done delete");
    }catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    });
    jbtInsert.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Insert");
            ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
            if (fileLength == 0)
            { 
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());
                currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
                System.out.println("client done insert");
                return;
            }
            String recordToInsert[] = { jtfName.getText(), jtfStreet.getText(), jtfCity.getText(),
                    jtfState.getText(), jtfZip.getText()};
            numberOfRecordsToCopy = FromServer.readLong(); 
            for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecordsToCopy; i++ )
            { 
                readAddress();
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());                        
            }
            //readAddress();
            jtfName.setText(recordToInsert[0]);
            jtfStreet.setText(recordToInsert[1]);
            jtfCity.setText(recordToInsert[2]);
            jtfState.setText(recordToInsert[3]);
            jtfZip.setText(recordToInsert[4]);
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
            ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText());
            readAddress();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done insert");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtDuplicate.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Duplicate");
            //ToServer.writeLong(currentPosition);
            numberOfRecords = FromServer.readLong(); 
            for (int i=0; i < numberOfRecords; i++ )
            {
                readAddress();
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfName.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfStreet.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfCity.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfState.getText());
                ToServer.writeUTF(jtfZip.getText()); 
            }
            if (numberOfRecords>0) readAddress();
            currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
            System.out.println("client done duplicate");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    jbtDoSort.setOnAction(e ->
    {   
        try {
            fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
            ToServer.writeUTF("Sort");
            ToServer.writeBoolean(jrbSortDecsend.isSelected());
            ToServer.writeInt(jcbSortChoices.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (fileLength > 0) readAddress();
        System.out.println("client done sort");

    });

    /** Add to details and run Application **/
    Scene scene = new Scene (mainPane, -100, -100);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Complex Address System"); // Set the window title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the window
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the window
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest( new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
        public void handle(WindowEvent event){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }); 
}

private void first() {
    try {
        fileLength = FromServer.readLong();
        ToServer.writeUTF("First");
        ToServer.flush();
        if (fileLength > 0) readAddress();
        currentPosition = FromServer.readLong();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
private void growChildren(GridPane pane)
{ pane.getChildren().forEach(chiled ->
{   pane.setHgrow(chiled, Priority.ALWAYS);
pane.setVgrow(chiled, Priority.ALWAYS);
});
}

private void readAddress() {

    try {
        String name = FromServer.readUTF();
        String street = FromServer.readUTF();
        String city = FromServer.readUTF();
        String state = FromServer.readUTF();
        String zip = FromServer.readUTF();
        jtfName.setText(name);
        jtfStreet.setText(street);
        jtfCity.setText(city);
        jtfState.setText(state);
        jtfZip.setText(zip);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void clearTextFields() {
    jtfName.setText(null);
    jtfStreet.setText(null);
    jtfCity.setText(null);
    jtfState.setText(null);
    jtfZip.setText(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{ launch(args);
}

}
```